# Pass JSP output stream to a method

Tags: java, jsp

I've created a class MyClass that intends to output a large amount of text to a JSP. Rather than having the MyClass object return a string to be displayed on the page, I figured it would be a better idea for the MyClass object to use the page's output stream. Is this a good/possible idea?

In testing possible ways to do this...

These output the text, but it displays before the body of the page:

```
response.getWriter().append("test1");
response.getWriter().println("test2");
response.getWriter().write("test3");
```

This errors and tells me the output stream was already *gotten*:

```
response.getOutputStream().println("test4");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`response.getWriter()` will give you different writer than one used in JSP. If you want to write to same writer as JSP page is using, you need to use `out` variable from JSP page. Difference is that JSP uses buffering on top of standard `response.getWriter()`. That's why you see your data written to `response.getWriter()` before JSP body.

You cannot mix `response.getWriter()` and `response.getOutputStream()`. `out` variable in JSP is JspWriter instance wrapping writer obtained `response.getWriter()` so calling `response.getOutputStream()` will fail.

What you should do in your JSP:

```
<%
  new MyClass().writeToWriter(out);
%>
```

And in MyClass:

```
public void writeToWriter(Writer w) {
    w.println("My data appended to correct writer");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the class return you an iterator that generates the text one small chunk at a time. You could then iterate through the iterator in the JSP and print the data chunks at the appropriate location.